# How to generate a longer isset() statement in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an interesting question today. Lets say I have an array of form fields:

```
array('field1', 'field2', 'field3');
```

I would basically want to generate an if statement which check if all of the provided fields are exists or not.

So something like this:

```
function ($array){
   $stm = '';
   foreach($array as $key){
      $stm .= 'isset($_POST['.$key.']) && ';
   }
   if (rtrim($stm, ' && ')){
      echo 'Fields are exists.';
```

}
}

The problem with the above function is that it takes the created statement as a String and not a variable, so it always exsits. Is there any way that I can generate something like this, which would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about this the wrong way. If I understood correctly, you have an array of values, that are also `POST` keys, and you want to check if all of them are set. In this case I'd do something like:

```
function isset_multiple($array){
    foreach($array as $post_key){
        if(!isset($_POST[$post_key])) // if one of them is not set, return false
            return false;
    }
    return true; // none of the foreach loops returned false, so all must be set
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer man, yeah, I'm a bit tired. This is the real way it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check if array keys are set by using variable names, for example

```
$keyName = "field1";

if ( isset($_POST[$keyName]) === true ) { /* ... */ }
```

The example above can be implemented in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the `isset` and count:

```
function ($array){
  $count = 0;
  foreach($array as $key){
    if (isset($_POST[$key]) $count++;
    else // you can already exit here...
  }
  if (count($array) === $count){
    echo 'All fields exist.';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
function arrayHasKeys(array $array, array $keys)
{
    return !((bool) array_diff_key($array, $keys));
}

var_dump(arrayHasKeys($_POST, array('field1', 'field2', 'field3')));
```

Its quite simple and reusable. Its not a good practice to use global vars inside a function.